# Review notification

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Yesterday i have seen a new menu in top bar section of my profile named as review. I conclude that it is due completing 500 reputation.

Today when i have clicked on review menu i have seen 1 post present for review. I have reviewed that post and in that page saw there are lots of post present for close and think about the question ask by @Molot  **"Please review close votes!"**.

```
But i think it will be better if their is a notification present in review menu for like,
 friend request in social networking site. Then post will be easily reviewed by user.
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't think it will workout because it will flood the notification and also it is a common task, not for single user.

Comment: I must admit I don't understand what feature you are requesting is supposed to look like. Anyway, thank you for reviewing what you can :) As this is a feature request, please remember that downvotes means "I don't want this feature", not "this question is badly written" (of course people tend to not want features they can't understand, that's normal).

Comment: @Bala and Molot thanks for your valuable comments. My aim is to writing this question is, there should not be a question present which is not reviewed.

Comment: @Smalution As far as I know you get notification for only Suggested Edits.(need 2k reputation to review it). I think users having 15k reputation get notification for all reviews. (I read that somewhere in meta or here I don't remember)

Comment: @KrishnaMohan yes, you are right. for "First Posts" and "Late Answers" - 500, "Low Quality Posts" and "Suggested Edits" - 2k, "Close Votes" and "Reopen Votes" - 3k, reputation needed for review. but my question is regarding notification not for permission.